# What are the hidden achievements in A Short Hike?

Tags: achievements, a-short-hike

I want to get all of the achievements for A Short Hike (there are only 8 of them, and I already have 4 so far). The ones I can see look easy, but two of them are hidden. What are the hidden achievements for A Short Hike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of them is to score 30 hits in beachstickball. the other you have to talk to the guy who gave you Golden Feathers and Provincial Park Hat at 5PM after reading the Hawk Peak Provincial Park sign first

Comment: 5pm as in 5pm system time, or is there some way of telling in game time?

Comment: @Unionhawk - You've probably already figured this out, but for those in the future:
5PM as in system time; in-game time is system time.